# Disable default email sending in AWS Cognito

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

I'm using AWS Cognito for authentication in my next js app.
And I'm using `aws-amplify` npm package to signup/signin the user.

```js
import {
  Auth
} from "aws-amplify"
import {
  SendTemplatedEmailCommand
} from "@aws-sdk/client-ses"
const handleRegister = async() => {

  try {
    await Auth.signUp({
      username: formik.values.email,
      password: formik.values.password,
    })
    //send email with aws sdk v3
    const emailBody = new SendTemplatedEmailCommand({
      Destination: {
        ToAddresses: ["receiver@example.com"]
      },
      TemplateData: JSON.stringify({
        data: emailData
      }),
      Source: "verified@email.com",
      Template: "welcome",
    })
    await client.send(emailBody)
    formik.resetForm()
    notification.success({
      message: "User registered in AWS Congito"
    })
  } catch (e) {
    notification.error({
      message: e.message
    })
  }
}
```

I've configured to use AWS SES for sending email (email also verified) in messaging tab.

[image]

When I register new user, I get email from AWS SES configured email. But AWS Cognito is also sending its default email with content.

```
Please click the link below to verify your email address. {##Verify Email##}
```

I want email from AWS SES configured email only not default email from Cognito.

How do i disable sending default email from Cognito ?

The new AWS Console UI is clean but confusing at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

How about when creating userpool just disabling :

*Allow Cognito to automatically send messages to verify and confirm - Recommended*

Comment: So I cannot disable after I've already created user pool ?

Comment: I tried creating userpool with aws ses as default email sender. I get the same result.
Received 2 emails . 1 from cognito 1 from aws ses

Comment: There are probably some other settings involved then such as lambda triggers reacting to auth events sending emails.

>So I cannot disable after I've already created user pool ?

I seems to me that you cannot.